# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.drawable.Drawable

Tags: react-native

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.drawable.Drawable android.graphics.drawable.Drawable$ConstantState.newDrawable(android.content.res.Resources)' on a null object reference

Hlow Friends I m Getting This Crash In App Center In Live App.

Please Check This ScreenShot And Revert To Me How Can i Fixed That.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/17J79z5_aSUX8PgAKgT_n2mLV9AjQITtq/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: actually this is an exception of app center its coming in live application..